# Flask эндпоинт не работает более, чем с одним параметром

Tags: python, flask

Есть приложение на Flask , я пытаюсь сделать несколько параметров для запроса по API.

Файл Mybook

```
class MybookPrew(Resource):
    def get(self, param1, param2, param3):
        #some logic
        return url_responce

class BookprewEN (MybookPrew):
    self.language = 'EN'

class BookprewRU (MybookPrew):
    self.language = 'RU'

class BookprewUA (MybookPrew):
    self.language = 'UA'
```

Файл flask_api которые запускает API

```
from Mybook import Book_prewEN, Book_prewUA, Book_prewRU

app = Flask(Myproject)
api = restful.Api(app)

book_param1 = '/book/s%/param3=<int:param1>'
book_param2 = '/book/s%/param3=<int:param2>'
book_param3 = '/book/s%/param3=<int:param3>'

api.add_resource(Mybook.BookprewEN, book_param1 %'en', book_param1 %'en', book_param1 %'en')
api.add_resource(Mybook.BookprewRU, book_param1 %'ru', book_param2 %'ru', book_param3 %'ru')
api.add_resource(Mybook.BookprewUA, book_param1 %'ua', book_param2 %'ua', book_param3 %'ua')
```

Ошибка в том, что, когда я отправляю запрос в эндпоинт (указан ниже), второй параметр `param2` не работает. То есть, отрабатывает только один. При выводе `print(param2)` в методе `get` класса `MybookPrew` я получаю None. При этом, если их поменять местами, то param2 будет отрабатывать, а param1 вернёт `None`. В чём может быть ошибка ?

```
https://my_project_ip/book/ua/param1=23?param2=3
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48095713/accepting-multiple-parameters-in-flask-restful-add-resource

Comment: @Jack_oS спасибо за ссылку. На мне не подходит такая реализация. я изменил немного текст. У меня два файла и мне нужно именно такая реализация :(